# Destroying model objects when user no longer exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails User and Track model where a User tracks another user similar to how people follow on Twitter.

```
User.rb
has_many :tracks, :dependent => :destroy 

Track.rb
belongs_to :user
```

The Track model stores the following attributes:

```
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "tracker_user_id"
```

Naturally, if the User who creates the Track (user_id) deletes their account then the Track will be destroyed.

If the User who is being tracked (tracker_user_id) deletes their account, what's the best way to destroy the track also?

At the moment I display @user.tracks.size in the view which gives an incorrect value if the tracked User has deleted their account.

Comment: Can you show what is the association set up you have between User and track based on `tracker_user_id` foreign key?

Comment: I'm a junior ruby dev so have limited knowledge... in my Track controller I have: @track.tracker_user_id = params[:tracked_id] and in the view <%= link_to "Track", tracks_path(current_user, tracked_id: @user.id), method: :post, class: "button" %>

Comment: I am asking because to understand how the relationship works. So each *track* is being created to track only 1 user?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: So create another `has_one` and `belongs_to` relationship between User and Task model based on `tracker_user_id` as foreign key. And then you can delete the task, when parent user ( `tracker_user_id`) is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: You should also take a look to self referential association http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast